# Laravel github branches vendor file in gitignore

Tags: php, laravel, git

I made a new branch, because I need to update a certain dependency and adjust the code so the new version works.

After I pushed the branch. I switched to master and noticed that the package is also updated. I had to revert the update.

I noticed that this happened because the `/vendor/` file is included in the `.gitignore`. After some reading I understand why. In case, I want to pull the project somewhere else, I should use composer install to install the dependencies.

But I am thinking, is it really worth it? I just could upload the whole vendor folder and when I pull it somewhere it would just work. **The only downside it, that the vendor folder may be huge, am I correct?**

I do not see an other option how I would be able to update and test a dependency on a different branch.

---

Is it save to remove the vendor folder from the `.gitignore`?

Is size the only reason why it is there?

---

If I keep the vendor folder in `.gitignore`, which seems to be suggested everywhere, how do I update a dependency on a branch only without destroying master?

I could recreate the whole vendor folder every time, but thats insane, that sounds really wrong.

Comment: You dont need to add vendor folder to your git, because vendor dependencies will be added by `composer install` itself. add the vendor folder to the `.gitignore` file, then  only add `.gitignore` by `git add .gitignore` then commit it. Now vendor will be ignored in your git `git status`

Comment: Qucik search on composer gave this:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md

Comment: Okay, but how should I use github branches to update a dependency?

Comment: you need to run composer install everytime you swap branch

Comment: @Ebski I just had this idea, this feels somehow wrong, is this really how it is done?

Comment: I can't say that it's how it's done all over, but it's an easy way to handle different dependencies on different branches.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to have vendor folder not in repo.
composer.json file should pushed to git repo. You just to run `composer install` each time when you change anything in composer.json it will sync vendor folder with composer.json, on first time `composer install` will create composer.lock file to lock the versions of packages,

[To see more](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)

Answer (score 0):

I'm OK with running `composer install` every time that I swap the branches.
But I have an idea for your case you could keep `vendor` in your main .gitignore file then go to the vendor folder and initialize a git repo in that folder from now on you are able to switch between branches in that sub git repository.
Note: be aware that you should also change branches in the main repo when you want to test your dependencies. (It's better to keep the name of the main repository's branch and the sub repository's branch the same.)

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks for that.